# Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 Offline Network Layout - Packages Missing from Layout Cache

Tags: visual-studio

I'm attempting to create a network layout of a selection of the latest Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools components (v16.11.12) using the following command:

```
vs_BuildTools.exe --layout .\ --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NodeBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VisualStudioExtensionBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools --includeRecommended --lang en-US
```

This downloads the relevant packages as expected so next want to test the installation using the Response.json file with the following command:

```
vs_setup.exe --wait --noUpdateInstaller --noWeb --in CustomInstall.json
```

CustomInstall.json contents:

```
{
  "installChannelUri": ".\\ChannelManifest.json",
  "channelUri": "https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/channel",
  "installCatalogUri": ".\\Catalog.json",
  "channelId": "VisualStudio.16.Release",
  "productId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools",

  "includeRecommended": true,
  "quiet": true,
  "norestart": true,
  
  "addProductLang": [
    "en-US"
    ],

    "add": [
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataBuildTools",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NodeBuildTools",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VisualStudioExtensionBuildTools",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools",
    ]
}
```

The problem is that the pre-check verification fails with the message

> "Pre-check verification: The following required packages are missing from the layout cache"

This message is followed by a large swathe of packages that are indeed missing, but if these are required, I'd expect the initial layout command to include these! The suggestion is to run the fix command:

```
vs_setup.exe --layout  C:\Temp\2019BuildTools_16_11_11 --fix
```

However, this just completes saying everything's fine.

Even running the layout command again in another directory, but this time downloading all packages doesn't provide what it says is missing so am a bit stumped as to why the installer is looking for packages that aren't included as part of the full install e.g. error log says 'Microsoft.Net.Core.BootstrapperPackages,version=5.0.0.45' is missing but only 'Microsoft.Net.Core.BootstrapperPackages,version=5.0.0.47' is available in the cache.

I initially created this post in the wrong forum but thought I'd solved it due to having the "installOptional" parameter present in my CustomInstall.json file but not in the layout command, however, looks like it's still not working after removing it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and can't figure out how to fix it. I've done this successfully several times over the years. This is the first time that I cannot get it to work.

Comment: I spent most of the day trying to make this work. No luck. Tomorrow, I'm going to see if anybody else has reported this to Microsoft yet.

Comment: I got it to work. You will need to run this command without any arguments:

      Offline\vs_professional.exe

You will get many errors/warnings, but if you keep clicking the Continue button several times, it should complete the update. It seems that Microsoft broke the --noWeb argument, so that you can no longer use that.

Comment: I am facing this issue while trying to install build tools.  There is no internet for the server and while running with noWeb option it is showing similar message and stays there. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

**For me what worked was to remove the `--noWeb` argument.**

I followed [this Miscrosoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) and created a layout with the command.

```
vs_enterprise.exe --layout D:\localVSlayout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure --lang en-US
```

Later when I try to install it using,

```
D:\localVSlayout\vs_enterprise.exe --noWeb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure --includeOptional
```

I got this error **"the following required packages are missing from the layout cache"**

What worked was simply remove the `--noWeb` argument from the command.

```
D:\localVSlayout\vs_enterprise.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure --includeOptional
```